# Flag duplicate "what have you tried" comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, comment-flags

There are often comments which asks "what have you tried" in different flavors. Even if this applies to somehow bad questions only I think this is just spam (if repeated). Also this takes the focus from the question and maybe reasonable comments. So I think they should be removed, how do think about this? Should such duplicate comments be flagged?

A recent example:
[image: A recent example]

Comment: Every highlighted comment but the first is completely pointless (and the first one isn't particularly helpful). I'd flag them all as "too chatty" _or_ I'd use the custom flag with a message along the lines of "poor guy is getting pestered with 'what have you tried' comments, purge, purge, purge".

Comment: You can flag them as obsolete?

Comment: As it takes six flags to delete a comment it's very rare to have them actually deleted. In such cases I would flag the post itself, choose "Other" and ask for comments cleanup.

Comment: At least one comment is fine that tells the OP about what is also mentioned in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask): "**Do your homework**  This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself."